# Update text in SVG within a PHP file

Tags: php, svg

I have a PHP file with an SVG part in it. Within the SVG part, I want to show one of my PHP variables which will update every 3 seconds.
I tried it with jquery but that just clears the space. This is my code with the jquery code I used. The SVG part has to be refreshed:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function updateDiv(){ 
            $( "#LA" ).load(window.location.href + "#LA")
        }, 3000);
    })
</script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">  
    <text id="LA" fill="#a3a3a3" font-size="35" font-family="FranklinGothic-Heavy, Franklin Gothic" font-weight="800">
        <tspan x="7.902" y="32">
        <?php echo $A_array[0][0]?>
        </tspan>
    </text>
</svg
```

I also tried to find for other solutions by searching for: "refresh PHP echo data" but the answers are mostly based on updating MySQL data. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: _"I have tried it with jquery but that just clears the space."_ - That's the code you should post and explain what you expect it to do and what actually happens. You might be on the right track but only have some implementation issue, which is exactly what we're here to help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors in your code:
-you are missing a space before the #LA when reloading
-you have to define the id="LA" one level deeper: inside the tspan.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Auto reload SVG</title>
      <meta name="description" content="Auto reload SVG">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
      <script> 
         $(document).ready(function(){
                         setInterval(function updateDiv(){ 
                                         $( "#test" ).load(window.location.href + " #test")
                                         $( "#LA" ).load(window.location.href + " #LA")
                         }, 2000);
         })
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>
         <span id="test">
         <?php echo rand(10,100); ?>
         </span>
      </h1>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
         <text fill="#a3a3a3" font-size="35" font-family="FranklinGothic-Heavy, Franklin Gothic" font-weight="800">
            <tspan x="7.902" y="32" id="LA">
               <?php echo rand(100,1000); ?>
            </tspan>
         </text>
      </svg>
   </body>
</html>
```

One problem with above solution is that it doesn't scale very well with higher frequency and more data numbers to show, because the [load() method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) loads the complete page including all scripts. Then it filters out the supplied #id content.

Better is to separate out the data from the page itself and use the [jQuery get() method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to call this data endpoint.

You can see it went down from 84KB to only 0.26KB excluding the FaviconLoader.jsm per call.

[image]